# How do i combine these .htaccess commands?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

thats for www/non www redirection

and this is for my maintenance page

```
ErrorDocument 503 /system/maintenance.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$  -  [redirect=503,last]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Putting them one after another doesn't work?

Comment: i didnt know if that's the wrong way to do it

Comment: It depends on which one you want to be applied first.

Comment: Should i delete the 2nd rewrite engine? if you just write it out as an answer ill mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which one you want to be applied first and if the `RewriteBase` can be applied to both set of rules (I'm assuming it can because the 2nd rule doesn't really care what the base is). You can also remove the duplicate `RewriteEngine On` directives:

```
# this is more or less something separate from rewrite engine
ErrorDocument 503 /system/maintenance.html

# turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do www to non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle maintenance
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/system/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$  -  [redirect=503,last]
```

This order means even if maintanence, the www to non-www still happens. If they were the other way around, you'd get maintanence handled regardless of whether the hostname was www or non-www.

Comment: @Tallboy No, the `ErrorDocument` just declares that a 503 error needs to be handled by `/system/maintenance.html`. You only need to declare it ones, and you can put that anywhere. I moved it up top so you can enterchange the two rules to see which behavior you'd rather have.